# Translate Matlab code to Python

Tags: python, algorithm, matlab, numpy, crc16

I have a problem with this algorithm:

```
function crc16 = crc16eval(D)
% CRC16EVAL CRC-CCITT check with the polynomial: x^16+x^12+x^5+1
D = uint16(D);
crchi = 255;
crclo = 255;
t = '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';
crc16htab = hex2dec(reshape(t,2,length(t)/2)');
t = '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';
crc16ltab = hex2dec(reshape(t,2,length(t)/2)');
for k = 1:length(D)
    ix = double(bitxor(crchi,D(k)))+1;
    crchi = bitxor(crclo,crc16htab(ix));
    crclo = crc16ltab(ix);
end
crc16 = crchi*256+crclo;
end
```

I need translate that code to Python, and I have done the next:

```
def crc16eval(D):
    crchi = 255
    crclo = 255
    t = '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'
    # crc16htab = hex2dec(reshape(t,2,length(t)/2)');

    tarray = [int(n, 16) for n in t] # Recorro el string t, y por cada caracter creo un nuevo entero en el array

    crc16htab = reshape(tarray, (2, (len(t)/2) )).transpose()
    #print crc16htab

    t = '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'
    # crc16ltab = hex2dec(reshape(t,2,length(t)/2)');

    tarray = [int(n, 16) for n in t] # Recorro el string t, y por cada caracter creo un nuevo entero en el array

    crc16ltab = reshape(tarray, (2, (len(t)/2))).transpose()
    #print crc16ltab

    for k in range(len(D)):
        ix = crchi ^ D[k]
        crchi = crclo ^ crc16htab[ix]
        crclo = crc16ltab[ix]

    return crchi*256+crclo
```

My problem is the next:

When I execute de Python code, It's take a loooong time to calculate de xor, I think the the problem is that

```
crclo = crc16ltab[ix]
```

is a matrix and that's take a long time to calculate. Which is the problem?

The pseudo-code of this algorithm is the next:

```
The algorithm for the CRC-CCITT is below described. Note that all operations are on bytes.
A = new byte
B = temp byte
CRCHI = High byte (most significant) of the 16-bit CRC
CRCLO = Low byte (least significant) of the 16-bit CRC
START:
    FOR A = FIRST_BYTE TO LAST_BYTE IN BLOCK DO:
        A = A XOR CRCHI
        CRCHI = A
        SHIFT A RIGHT FOUR TIMES (ZERO FILL)
        A = A XOR CRCHI                  {IJKLMNOP}
        CRCHI = CRCLO                    { swap CRCHI, CRCLO }
        CRCLO = A
        ROTATE A LEFT 4 TIMES            {MNOPIJKL}
        B=A                              { temp save }
        ROTATE A LEFT ONCE               {NOPIJKLM}
        A = A AND $1F                    {000IJLLM}
        CRCHI = A XOR CRCHI
        A = B AND $F0                    {MNOP0000}
        CRCHI = A XOR CRCHI              { CRCHI complete }
        ROTATE B LEFT ONCE               {NOP0000M}
        B = B AND $ E0                   {NOP00000}
        CRCLO = B XOR CRCLO              { CRCLO complete }
    DOEND;
FINISH.
```

My question is: Why my python code take long time to execute? What is wrong? The problem I think is in

```
for k in range(len(D)):
    ix = crchi ^ D[k]
    crchi = crclo ^ crc16htab[ix]
    crclo = crc16ltab[ix]
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is this python2 or python3? Have you run a profiler instead of counting on your hunch?

Comment: Ok, now you should use a profiler (like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927628/how-can-i-profile-python-code-line-by-line) to find out which specific line takes the most time.

Comment: Btw, ^ is exponentiating in matlab but in python use ** (ex. crchi**D[k])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the final solution, too late to post here maybe... But I think that maybe It's useful for someone.

```
# CRC16EVAL CRC-CCITT check with the polynomial: x^16+x^12+x^5+1
def crc16eval(D):
    crchi = 255
    crclo = 255

    crc16htab = [0, 16, 32, 48, 64, 80, 96, 112, 129, 145, 161, 177, 193, 209, 225, 241, 18, 2, 50, 34, 82, 66, 114, 98, 147, 131, 179, 163, 211, 195, 243, 227, 36, 52, 4, 20, 100, 116, 68, 84, 165, 181, 133, 149, 229, 245, 197, 213, 54, 38, 22, 6, 118, 102, 86, 70, 183, 167, 151, 135, 247, 231, 215, 199, 72, 88, 104, 120, 8, 24, 40, 56, 201, 217, 233, 249, 137, 153, 169, 185, 90, 74, 122, 106, 26, 10, 58, 42, 219, 203, 251, 235, 155, 139, 187, 171, 108, 124, 76, 92, 44, 60, 12, 28, 237, 253, 205, 221, 173, 189, 141, 157, 126, 110, 94, 78, 62, 46, 30, 14, 255, 239, 223, 207, 191, 175, 159, 143, 145, 129, 177, 161, 209, 193, 241, 225, 16, 0, 48, 32, 80, 64, 112, 96, 131, 147, 163, 179, 195, 211, 227, 243, 2, 18, 34, 50, 66, 82, 98, 114, 181, 165, 149, 133, 245, 229, 213, 197, 52, 36, 20, 4, 116, 100, 84, 68, 167, 183, 135, 151, 231, 247, 199, 215, 38, 54, 6, 22, 102, 118, 70, 86, 217, 201, 249, 233, 153, 137, 185, 169, 88, 72, 120, 104, 24, 8, 56, 40, 203, 219, 235, 251, 139, 155, 171, 187, 74, 90, 106, 122, 10, 26, 42, 58, 253, 237, 221, 205, 189, 173, 157, 141, 124, 108, 92, 76, 60, 44, 28, 12, 239, 255, 207, 223, 175, 191, 143, 159, 110, 126, 78, 94, 46, 62, 14, 30]

    crc16ltab = [0, 33, 66, 99, 132, 165, 198, 231, 8, 41, 74, 107, 140, 173, 206, 239, 49, 16, 115, 82, 181, 148, 247, 214, 57, 24, 123, 90, 189, 156, 255, 222, 98, 67, 32, 1, 230, 199, 164, 133, 106, 75, 40, 9, 238, 207, 172, 141, 83, 114, 17, 48, 215, 246, 149, 180, 91, 122, 25, 56, 223, 254, 157, 188, 196, 229, 134, 167, 64, 97, 2, 35, 204, 237, 142, 175, 72, 105, 10, 43, 245, 212, 183, 150, 113, 80, 51, 18, 253, 220, 191, 158, 121, 88, 59, 26, 166, 135, 228, 197, 34, 3, 96, 65, 174, 143, 236, 205, 42, 11, 104, 73, 151, 182, 213, 244, 19, 50, 81, 112, 159, 190, 221, 252, 27, 58, 89, 120, 136, 169, 202, 235, 12, 45, 78, 111, 128, 161, 194, 227, 4, 37, 70, 103, 185, 152, 251, 218, 61, 28, 127, 94, 177, 144, 243, 210, 53, 20, 119, 86, 234, 203, 168, 137, 110, 79, 44, 13, 226, 195, 160, 129, 102, 71, 36, 5, 219, 250, 153, 184, 95, 126, 29, 60, 211, 242, 145, 176, 87, 118, 21, 52, 76, 109, 14, 47, 200, 233, 138, 171, 68, 101, 6, 39, 192, 225, 130, 163, 125, 92, 63, 30, 249, 216, 187, 154, 117, 84, 55, 22, 241, 208, 179, 146, 46, 15, 108, 77, 170, 139, 232, 201, 38, 7, 100, 69, 162, 131, 224, 193, 31, 62, 93, 124, 155, 186, 217, 248, 23, 54, 85, 116, 147, 178, 209, 240]

    for k in range(len(D)):
        ix = crchi ^ D[k]
        crchi = crclo ^ crc16htab[ix]
        crclo = crc16ltab[ix]

    return crchi*256+crclo
```

Antonio.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend a read of Ross Williams, [A painless guide to CRC algorigthms](http://www.riccibitti.com/crcguide.htm) which will teach you everything you ever wanted to know about CRC's and how to calculate them quickly.

Here is a conversion of the CCITT CRC algorithm used in the linux kernel.  It may or may not be the same as what you are calculating as (if you read the above) you'll realise that there are quite a lot of knobs to twiddle when calculating CRCs.

```
# This mysterious table is just the CRC of each possible byte. It can be
# computed using the standard bit-at-a-time methods. The polynomial can
# be seen in entry 128, 0x8408. This corresponds to x^0 + x^5 + x^12.
# Add the implicit x^16, and you have the standard CRC-CCITT.
# From linux kernel lib/crc-ccitt.c

_crc_table = (
        0x0000, 0x1189, 0x2312, 0x329b, 0x4624, 0x57ad, 0x6536, 0x74bf,
        0x8c48, 0x9dc1, 0xaf5a, 0xbed3, 0xca6c, 0xdbe5, 0xe97e, 0xf8f7,
        0x1081, 0x0108, 0x3393, 0x221a, 0x56a5, 0x472c, 0x75b7, 0x643e,
        0x9cc9, 0x8d40, 0xbfdb, 0xae52, 0xdaed, 0xcb64, 0xf9ff, 0xe876,
        0x2102, 0x308b, 0x0210, 0x1399, 0x6726, 0x76af, 0x4434, 0x55bd,
        0xad4a, 0xbcc3, 0x8e58, 0x9fd1, 0xeb6e, 0xfae7, 0xc87c, 0xd9f5,
        0x3183, 0x200a, 0x1291, 0x0318, 0x77a7, 0x662e, 0x54b5, 0x453c,
        0xbdcb, 0xac42, 0x9ed9, 0x8f50, 0xfbef, 0xea66, 0xd8fd, 0xc974,
        0x4204, 0x538d, 0x6116, 0x709f, 0x0420, 0x15a9, 0x2732, 0x36bb,
        0xce4c, 0xdfc5, 0xed5e, 0xfcd7, 0x8868, 0x99e1, 0xab7a, 0xbaf3,
        0x5285, 0x430c, 0x7197, 0x601e, 0x14a1, 0x0528, 0x37b3, 0x263a,
        0xdecd, 0xcf44, 0xfddf, 0xec56, 0x98e9, 0x8960, 0xbbfb, 0xaa72,
        0x6306, 0x728f, 0x4014, 0x519d, 0x2522, 0x34ab, 0x0630, 0x17b9,
        0xef4e, 0xfec7, 0xcc5c, 0xddd5, 0xa96a, 0xb8e3, 0x8a78, 0x9bf1,
        0x7387, 0x620e, 0x5095, 0x411c, 0x35a3, 0x242a, 0x16b1, 0x0738,
        0xffcf, 0xee46, 0xdcdd, 0xcd54, 0xb9eb, 0xa862, 0x9af9, 0x8b70,
        0x8408, 0x9581, 0xa71a, 0xb693, 0xc22c, 0xd3a5, 0xe13e, 0xf0b7,
        0x0840, 0x19c9, 0x2b52, 0x3adb, 0x4e64, 0x5fed, 0x6d76, 0x7cff,
        0x9489, 0x8500, 0xb79b, 0xa612, 0xd2ad, 0xc324, 0xf1bf, 0xe036,
        0x18c1, 0x0948, 0x3bd3, 0x2a5a, 0x5ee5, 0x4f6c, 0x7df7, 0x6c7e,
        0xa50a, 0xb483, 0x8618, 0x9791, 0xe32e, 0xf2a7, 0xc03c, 0xd1b5,
        0x2942, 0x38cb, 0x0a50, 0x1bd9, 0x6f66, 0x7eef, 0x4c74, 0x5dfd,
        0xb58b, 0xa402, 0x9699, 0x8710, 0xf3af, 0xe226, 0xd0bd, 0xc134,
        0x39c3, 0x284a, 0x1ad1, 0x0b58, 0x7fe7, 0x6e6e, 0x5cf5, 0x4d7c,
        0xc60c, 0xd785, 0xe51e, 0xf497, 0x8028, 0x91a1, 0xa33a, 0xb2b3,
        0x4a44, 0x5bcd, 0x6956, 0x78df, 0x0c60, 0x1de9, 0x2f72, 0x3efb,
        0xd68d, 0xc704, 0xf59f, 0xe416, 0x90a9, 0x8120, 0xb3bb, 0xa232,
        0x5ac5, 0x4b4c, 0x79d7, 0x685e, 0x1ce1, 0x0d68, 0x3ff3, 0x2e7a,
        0xe70e, 0xf687, 0xc41c, 0xd595, 0xa12a, 0xb0a3, 0x8238, 0x93b1,
        0x6b46, 0x7acf, 0x4854, 0x59dd, 0x2d62, 0x3ceb, 0x0e70, 0x1ff9,
        0xf78f, 0xe606, 0xd49d, 0xc514, 0xb1ab, 0xa022, 0x92b9, 0x8330,
        0x7bc7, 0x6a4e, 0x58d5, 0x495c, 0x3de3, 0x2c6a, 0x1ef1, 0x0f78
)

def update_crc(data, crc, table=_crc_table):
    """
    Add a byte to the crc calculation
    """
    return (crc >> 8) ^ table[(crc ^ data) & 0xff]

def calculate_crc(data, crc=0xFFFF, table=_crc_table):
    """
    Calculates the CRC for the data string passed in
    """
    for c in data:
        crc = update_crc(ord(c), crc, table)
    return crc

print "%04X" % calculate_crc("Hello")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to calculate CRC16 only (just result, not code), you could use  [PyCRC](http://www.tty1.net/pycrc/crc-models_en.html) or [CRC-16](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/crc16).

Comment: I tried use that packages, but pycrc uses other polynomial function. I need the x^16+x^12+x^5+1 polynomial
And that package uses: x^16 + x^15 + x^10 + x^3 polynomial