# Python code optimizing with the profile class

Tags: python, optimization, profile

My code has become really slow after some last changes I have done. A searching task takes 102 seconds instead of 2-3 seconds.

I've tried using the `profile` class in order to find the limiting function, and here is the output:

```
>>> import WebParser
>>>
>>> w = WebParser.LinksGrabber
>>>
>>> import cProfile
>>> cProfile.run("w.search('nicki minaj', 15)")
         50326 function calls in 102.745 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000  102.745  102.745 <string>:1(<module>)
        6    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 Config.py:110(__getattr__)
        1    0.000    0.000  102.745  102.745 LinksGrabber.py:427(search)
        5    0.000    0.000    0.002    0.000 Queue.py:107(put)
      911    0.040    0.000  102.726    0.113 Queue.py:150(get)
       ..................................
      }
     6836    0.022    0.000    0.022    0.000 {min}
      917    0.009    0.000    0.009    0.000 {thread.allocate_lock}
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {thread.get_ident}
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {thread.start_new_thread}
    6835  100.458    0.015  100.458    0.015 {time.sleep}
    11346    0.035    0.000    0.035    0.000 {time.time}
```

It shows that a `time.sleep` code is waiting for `100.458s`, but I can't find the code piece in my `WebParser.LinksGrabber` class.

How can I use `profile` to get more information about the slow piece of code?

Comment: You can use some [line-profiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927628/how-can-i-profile-python-code-line-by-line). Anyway, `time.sleep` is not sleeping for `100s`. It is sleeping for `0.015s` for `6835` times. Are almost 7k calls to `time.sleep` normal?

Comment: The easiest way to find the problem [*is this*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4299378/23771).

Answer (score 2):

I have a piece of boilerplate code I add in to programs I need to profile, which I can easily enable or disable by changing the `PROFILE` variable to `True` or `False`...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Should we profile the code?
PROFILE = True

# What proportion of the profile data should we keep?
PROFILE_LIMIT = 0.5         # 50%

# Where to store the raw profile data
PROFILE_DAT = 'profile.dat'

# Where to store the formatted profile data
PROFILE_TXT = 'profile.txt'


# Main code starts here
import time

def do_something():
    for i in range(5):
        time.sleep(0.1)

def do_something_else():
    for i in range(10):
        time.sleep(0.1)

def main():
    do_something()
    do_something_else()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    if PROFILE:
        import os, cProfile, pstats
        cProfile.runctx('main()', globals(), locals(), PROFILE_DAT)
        f = open(PROFILE_TXT, 'wb')
        for sort_key in 'time', 'cumulative':
            stats = pstats.Stats(PROFILE_DAT, stream=f)
            stats.sort_stats(sort_key)
            stats.print_stats(PROFILE_LIMIT)
            stats.strip_dirs()
            stats.sort_stats(sort_key)
            if sort_key == 'time':
                stats.print_callers(PROFILE_LIMIT)
            else:
                stats.print_callees(PROFILE_LIMIT)
        f.close()
        os.unlink(PROFILE_DAT)

    else:
        main()
```

...which creates a text file `profile.txt` containing...

1. The slowest functions (internally) along with where they're called from
2. The slowest functions (cumulatively) along with what they call

...which looks like this...

```
[...]

   Ordered by: internal time
   List reduced from 7 to 4 due to restriction <0.5>

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
       15    1.627    0.108    1.627    0.108 {time.sleep}
        1    0.000    0.000    1.092    1.092 foo.py:23(do_something_else)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.536    0.536 foo.py:19(do_something)
        1    0.000    0.000    1.628    1.628 foo.py:27(main)


[...]

Function                      was called by...
                                  ncalls  tottime  cumtime
{time.sleep}                  <-       5    0.535    0.535  foo.py:19(do_something)
                                      10    1.092    1.092  foo.py:23(do_something_else)
foo.py:23(do_something_else)  <-       1    0.000    1.092  foo.py:27(main)
foo.py:19(do_something)       <-       1    0.000    0.536  foo.py:27(main)
foo.py:27(main)               <-       1    0.000    1.628  <string>:1(<module>)


[...]

   Ordered by: cumulative time
   List reduced from 7 to 4 due to restriction <0.5>

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    1.628    1.628 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    1.628    1.628 foo.py:27(main)
       15    1.627    0.108    1.627    0.108 {time.sleep}
        1    0.000    0.000    1.092    1.092 foo.py:23(do_something_else)


[...]

Function                      called...
                                  ncalls  tottime  cumtime
<string>:1(<module>)          ->       1    0.000    1.628  foo.py:27(main)
foo.py:27(main)               ->       1    0.000    0.536  foo.py:19(do_something)
                                       1    0.000    1.092  foo.py:23(do_something_else)
{time.sleep}                  ->
foo.py:23(do_something_else)  ->       1    0.000    0.000  {range}
                                      10    1.092    1.092  {time.sleep}
```

...which is usually sufficient to track down where the code needs improving.