# python prime factorization performance

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, prime-factoring

I'm relatively new to python and I'm confused about the performance of two relatively simple blocks of code.  The first function generates a prime factorization of a number n given a list of primes.  The second generates a list of all factors of n.  I would have though `prime_factor` would be faster than `factors` (for the same n), but this is not the case.  I'm not looking for better algorithms, but rather I would like to understand why `prime_factor` is so much slower than `factors`.

```
def prime_factor(n, primes):
  prime_factors = []
  i = 0
  while n != 1:
      if n % primes[i] == 0:
          factor = primes[i]
          prime_factors.append(factor)
          n = n // factor
      else: i += 1
  return prime_factors

import math
def factors(n):
  if n == 0: return []
  factors = {1, n}
  for i in range(2, math.floor(n ** (1/2)) + 1):
      if n % i == 0:
          factors.add(i)
          factors.add(n // i)
  return list(factors)
```

Using the timeit module,

`{ i:factors(i) for i in range(1, 10000) }` takes 2.5 seconds

`{ i:prime_factor(i, primes) for i in range(1, 10000) }` takes 17 seconds

This is surprising to me.  `factors` checks every number from 1 to sqrt(n), while `prime_factor` only checks primes.  I would appreciate any help in understanding the performance characteristics of these two functions.

Thanks

Edit: (response to roliu)
Here is my code to generate a list of primes from 2 to `up_to`:

```
def primes_up_to(up_to):
  marked = [0] * up_to
  value = 3
  s = 2
  primes = [2]
  while value < up_to:
      if marked[value] == 0:
          primes.append(value)
          i = value
          while i < up_to:
              marked[i] = 1
              i += value
      value += 2
  return primes
```

Comment: related: [How can I profile python code line-by-line?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3927628/4279)

Comment: Where do you define the `primes` you supply to `prime_factors()`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Without seeing what you used for `primes`, we have to guess (we can't run your code).

But a big part of this is simply mathematics:  there are (very roughly speaking) about `n/log(n)` primes less than `n`, and that's a lot bigger than `sqrt(n)`.  So when you pass a prime, `prime_factor(n)` does a lot more work:  it goes through `O(n/log(n))` operations before finding the first prime factor (`n` itself!), while `factors(n)` gives up after `O(sqrt(n))` operations.

This can be very significant.  For example, `sqrt(10000)` is just 100, but there are 1229 primes less than 10000.  So `prime_factor(n)` **can** need to do over 10 times as much work to deal with the large primes in your range.

Comment: +1. Of course, prime_factor can also stop once it hits sqrt(n), since there can only be one prime factor of n greater than its square root.

Comment: Yes, in fact, if the list provided to prime_factor indeed contains only primes listed in ascending order, it will examine fewer numbers than factors before terminating; it gets to skip all the composite numbers!

Comment: All helpful to someone ;-), but the original poster said they weren't looking for a better algorithm - they just wanted to know why the **given code** behaves as it does.  I think it's pretty clear ;-)

Comment: @Tim Peters Perhaps I should clarify, since I wasn't disagreeing with your answer, just making sure OP sees the issue. For a value like m=2p, where p is prime, prime_factor(n) divides by 2 first, scans through every prime in [3,p] until concluding that p is prime. He could have stopped once he reached sqrt(p). If he did, prime_factor(n) should be about as fast or faster than factors(n). If he started with the largest prime smaller than sqrt(n), he could do even better.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was very helpful.  Adding a counter verified what you expected.  `prime_factor` looped about 87M times, and `factors` only looped 20M times.