# How can I make Python display the number of iterations it took to produce an answer?

Tags: python

I'm trying to find the number of bisections Python takes to produce the root of a function. For example, if I have the code:

```
import math
a=1
b=2
def f(x):
    return x**3+x-7
while b-a>0.001:
    c=(a+b)/2
    if f(a)*f(c)>0:
         a=c
    else:
         b=c
print(c)
```

This code will simply produce the desired answer. I would like to know how many times Python performed the bisection method and what were the values each time.

Comment: you can set a count variable which will count each time bisection method is used. Also add print to print the values that you desire to print each time.

Comment: import math
a=1
b=2
count = 0
def f(x):
    return x**3+x-7
while b-a>0.001:
    count += 1
    c=(a+b)/2
    if f(a)*f(c)>0:
         a=c
    else:
         b=c
print(c)

Answer (score 2):

You can use some profiler. For example **line_profiler**. You can install it simply:

```
pip install line_profiler
```

Look here:
[How can I profile python code line-by-line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927628/how-can-i-profile-python-code-line-by-line)