# how to profile python performance or each statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, profile

It seems that cProfile provides only time consumed for function calls. While this is useful in general, I need to find a way to profile python programs at the statement-level, i.e, how much time does each statement take? How could I do this ?

Comment: Use [`line_profiler`](https://pypi.org/project/line-profiler/)

Comment: Interesting! Do you have an example illustrating how it can be used?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I profile Python code line-by-line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927628/how-can-i-profile-python-code-line-by-line)

Comment: @roganjosh I did "pip install line-profiler", and then do not see how to use it... In particular, line-profiler is not a recognized command after installing the package.

Comment: Just realize that the name of the command for line-profiler is kernprof, a strange name that helps nobody:-)

Comment: @RandomDavis You are right! Same question.