# Can't get cython profiling line by line to work

Tags: python, profiling, cython, line-profiler

On the top of the .pyx file I've added:

```
# cython: linetrace=True
# distutils: define_macros=CYTHON_TRACE_NOGIL=1 CYTHON_TRACE=1
```

I've tried also putting macros in my setup file.

Then I'm running:

```
from mycythonmodule import func
profile = line_profiler.LineProfiler(func)
profile.runcall(func)
profile.print_stats()
```

It prints the file but no timing, nor number of call...
The cython code is significantly slower,  compared to without the tags on the top of the .pyx

When I'm using [kernprof](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3927671), .prof file is nearly empty.

Any idea ?