# Is there a Python library that shows execution time per line?

Tags: python, performance, profiling, stack-trace, execution-time

I have found this library called `heartrate` which shows how many times each line has been hit. I'm wondering if there is a similar library that can show the execution time of each line? Sometimes a single line can be a bottleneck of a program.

[image]

Comment: This is duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62382967/4601890. Also, I recommend [pycharm line profiler plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/16536-line-profiler)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a library called `pyheat`.

you can install by

```
pip install py-heat
```

and import it using `from pyheat import PyHeat`

*Pyheat can be used to generate a heatmap of time numbers for each line of code for a Python module. Pass the path of the Python file as a parameter to the PyHeat function.*

```
ph = PyHeat('merge_sort.py')  # mergesort.py is the example given
ph.create_heatmap()
ph.show_heatmap()
```

Please look into this https://github.com/csurfer/pyheat

Answer (score -1):

I've built a small library [perf_tool](https://github.com/glaucouri/perf_tool) that can perform this kind of benchmarks.

It can be used to profile pieces of codes and also single lines using decorators, here is a simple example:

```
 from perf_tool import PerfTool
 with PerfTool('test'):
    <The code to be profiled>


Calling it the result is a report showing some metrics like this:

================== PerfTool ==================
task                     |aver(s) |sum(s)  |count   |std     
main                     |   0.065|   0.065|       1|   0.000
  +-test                 |   0.050|   0.005|      10|   0.002
```

There are also other libraries in that field like [linetimer](https://github.com/justasb/linetimer)

Comment: fyi link-only answers are not valid answers. Plus the OP's question is off-topic (tool/product/service recommendation)

Comment: Py profiling is a hot topic so far. Not clear to me why it should be off-topic